# Object and reference to it in Java

Tags: java, object, reference

I came accross this article:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174371&seqNum=4

and I do not think it is correct picture used to show references to object if I create variables in such way:

```
pt1 = new Point(100,100)
pt2 = new Point(100,100)
```

My question is:

which situation takes place if I create two points as above, how the references to object/objects looks like? (I assume Option 1 is correct):

Option1:

```
pt1 ---->[Point object: 100, 100]

pt2 ---->[Point object: 100, 100]
```

Option2:

```
pt1 ----> |----------------------|
          |Point object: 100, 100|
pt2 ----> |----------------------|
```

Comment: `new` means new. Each `Point` you made is a new object.

Answer (score 3):

If you say:

```
pt1 = new Point(100,100) 
pt2 = new Point(100,100)
```

then option 1 is correct.

If you say:

```
pt1 = new Point(100,100)
pt2 = pt1
```

then option 2 occurs

Comment: I agree hence why I think there should be two pictures included in the mentioned article for any beginners coming across such information. Thank you for your answer anyway.

Comment: @BlueTomato writing to the author of the article stands a greater chance of getting this change made than posting a question here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right, Option 1 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out *why* only option 1 can be correct: think about what the consequences would be if option 2 was correct:

```
pt1 = new Point(100,100)
pt2 = new Point(100,100)

pt1.x = 200

System.out.println(pt2.x)
```

What would that print?

If references to similar objects automatically pointed to the same memory, modifying one would modify the other, but only in situations where a similar object is created. That would be surprising behavior to say the least.

It should be noted though that in languages that emphasise immutability, option 2 is possible, since you have a guarantee that the object will never change.